# email a dashboard time to time in wave analytics

Tags: analytics, einstein-analytics

I was trying to email a dashboard time to time in wave analytics. I only can send a snapshot, or a link or give access but, I want to send them time to time basis through email. how to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this capabilities do not exist yet in Wave.